# \pagecolor ignored when preview package used

Tags: color, preview, pagecolor

When I use the `standalone` package's `preview` option, `pagecolor` is ignored.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagecolor{red}

\begin{document}

\color{blue} \lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

[image: rendered MWE]

How can I use `preview` with a background color?

Comment: why do you want to use preview?

Comment: It is for LaTeX rendering in a messaging service, where the results are sent as images.

Comment: No I meant why are you need the preview option? Why don't you use a minipage?